# How can I vertically center rotated text using Flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

How can I vertically center rotated text using flexbox layout? I want something that looks like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: #efefef; }

body > div {
  align-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
}

body > div > div {
  flex: 1;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Where did I go?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` and center horizontally and vertically using:

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

(and you don't need the `flex: 1`!)

Also removed the browser margin and added in `box-sizing: border-box` to add the finishing touches.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
body > div {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
body > div > div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Where did I go?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by changing a couple things in your code:

1. Give your text a `white-space: nowrap;`.
2. Give your containing div a `justify-content: center;`.
3. In your containing div, change `align-content` to `align-items`.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: #efefef; }

body > div {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
}

body > div > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Where did I go?
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note** You can also remove `flex: 1;` from your inner div, as it is not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks Hunter. @kukkuz barely beat you to the answer, so I'll accept his and upvote yours. Appreciate it.

Comment: Actually I posted mine first, haha. But that's fine :)

Comment: @MattPowell ya, actually he beat me to it... and you can be generous with upvote :)

Comment: Haha, I'll give you some love @kukkuz ;D + 1

Comment: returning it too :)